# Query returning an empty object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've tried to read from `MongoDB` database the list of equipments via `mongoose` and the result I got is an empty array, even if inside database exist a document.

Bellow you can see the main files from the projects:

`server.js`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = require('./app');

const DB_URI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/metrolog';

mongoose
  .connect(DB_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB!');
  });

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, console.log(`Listening on port: ${port}`));
```

`app.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const routerEquip = require('./routerEquip');

const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());


app.use('/api/equip', routerEquip);

module.exports = app;
```

`routes.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const controllerEquip = require('./../controllers/equip');

const router = express.Router();

router.route('/').get(controllerEquip.getEquips);

module.exports = router;
```

`models/equip.js`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const schemaEquip = new mongoose.Schema({
  description: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    maxlength: 50
  },
  model: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    maxlength: 50
  }
});

const Equip = mongoose.model('Equip', schemaEquip);

module.exports = Equip;
```

`controllers/equip.js`

```
const Equip = require('./../models/equip');

exports.getEquips = async (req, res) => {
  const equip = await Equip.find();

  res.status(200).json({
    result: 'success',
    rows: equip.length,
    data: { equip }
 });
```

The document from `MongoDB`:

[screenshot from MongoDB Compass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/za7Q9.png)

By accessing the URL `http://localhost:3000/api/equip` the result I get is:

```
{
    "result": "success",
    "rows": 0,
    "data": {
        "equip": []
    }
}
```

Please help me to understand why the command `const equip = await Equip.find();` doesn't get any value. What am I doing wrong?

Remarks:

- I use the latest stable versions of `nodeJS`, `express` and
  `mongoose`
- This is my first project I made in `nodeJS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose consider the collection name by making plural of first parameter of your model creation. So in the above case it converts **Equip** to **Equips** and looks for a collection with this name which actually does not exists. To avoid this gotcha what you can do is pass the collection name as the third parameter in you model implementation. Your model generation code will look like:

```
const Equip = mongoose.model('Equip', schemaEquip, 'equip');
```

Hope this helps :)